# Disposing SharePoint Objects

Tags: 2013, dispose, ssom

If you open a SharePoint list like this

```
var site = new SPSite(url);
var web = site.OpenWeb();
var list = web.Lists["ListName"];
```

Is it OK to dispose site and web through properties of the list?

```
var web = list.ParentWeb;
var site = web.Site;
web.Dispose();
site.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's completely fine.

Either you can use like below code in using block:

```
using(SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite("http://server"))
{
  using(SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPSite.OpenWeb())
   {
       str = oSPWeb.Title;
       str = oSPWeb.Url;
   }
}
```

You can get more information from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248.aspx)

Reference:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687949.aspx
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rogerla/2008/02/12/sharepoint-2007-and-wss-3-0-dispose-patterns-by-example/

Answer (score 1):

If you are explicitly creating object for each of them, then you are supposed to dispose that object also.

```
var site = new SPSite(url);
var web = site.OpenWeb();
var list = web.Lists["ListName"];
```

Here you will need to dispose each object explicitly as a good coding practice like this:

```
web.Dispose();
site.Dispose();
```

Comment: I don't think SPLists can be disposed